# How to convert value of type Int to expected argument type Bool

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to check if `1Array.count` is greater than the counts of three other arrays, `2Array`, `3Array`, and `4Array`:

```
if 1Array.count > 2Array.count && 3Array.count && 4Array.count {
    // code
}
```

but I have this error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Bool'
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: If you want arrays to be non-empty, check that `count > 0`.

Comment: Unrelated, but a variable name cannot start with a digit.

Comment: @AlexF you should use `isEmpty` rather than `count>0` for that purpose.

Comment: There is no way to find out which array has the most values in a single `if` statement.  You will need a series of if/else statements in the form shown by @Moe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intent is to make sure that 1Array count is greater than all the other collections count you can simply compare it against the maximum value of them:

```
if array1.count > max(array2.count, array3.count, array4.count) {
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to check that all arrays are < 1Array then your `If` stmt needs to read like this:

```
if 1Array.count > 2Array.count && 1Array.count > 3Array.count && 1Array.count > 4Array.count {
}
```

Better yet:

```
if array1.count > array2.count, array1.count > array3.count, array1.count > array4.count {
    }
```

Rename the variables might be good too as I show in the above example.